# EF Core relations for generic translations table

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm trying to achieve this schema for DB translations (with `TitleTxId`, `DescriptionTxtId` and `Translations` tables):

[image]

But I can't setup relationships for it to work properly. I don't want to have `ProductId` inside `Translations` - I want `Translations` to be "generic".

Can somebody write or suggest how to write relationship with Fluent API?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Translatable models with Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112013/translatable-models-with-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks, but from what I see, using this approach would mean that each entity would need to have Translation model with predefined columns  to be translated. If that's correct, then that's different approach and not really what I'd like and need.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't really figure out the correct way to do it with db schema as in my question. Ended up creating a separate translations table per entity and with that, I can use them with ease of navigational properties. Will have a lot of "duplicated" tables, but it seems like a more proper way to do it, at least with ef core.

[image]